# Read pdf with fraction where fraction as superscript in c#

Tags: c#, itext

I have a pdf with lot of superscript characters
when i parse it with itextsharp the result shows © , ƒ in place of superscript values.

Is there is any way to parse it as numbers or usual text

Comment: Can you extract the characters with Acrobat? It would be useful to post the PDF.

Comment: Such errors in extracted text usually are due to documents having incomplete or even outright incorrect text extraction information. Thus, please share the pdf for analysis.